# Form is not aligned properly after introducing struts2 tag

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, themes

[image]

I want to align in one line but after I injected struts2 tags ..the fields are not aligned in one line.Please help me.I am beginner to struts2 but I tried my best to solve it but in vain.I am pretty sure that there must be some problems related to div tag but where is the exact problem that I am not able to figure out.
Below is my code of jsp page.

```xml
    <!-- Main content -->
    <div>
    <s:form action="UpdateUserRoleByAdmin">

    <s:iterator value="selectUserList">

        <section class="content"> <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->


            <div class="row">
                <div class="contetpanel">

                    <div>
                        <div class="crevtbl">
                            <div class="crevtblRow">
                                <div class="crevtblCell">Name</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                    <s:textfield name="updateuser.fullName" value="%{fullName}"
                                        size="40" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="crevtblRow">
                                <div class="crevtblCell">Address</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                    <s:textfield name="updateuser.userAddress"
                                        value="%{userAddress}" size="40" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="crevtblRow">
                            <div class="crevtblCell">Username</div>
                            <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div>
                            <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                <s:textfield name="updateuser.userName"
                                    value="%{userName}" size="40"/>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                            <div class="crevtblRow">
                                <div class="crevtblCell">Password</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                    <s:textfield name="updateuser.passWord" value="%{passWord}"
                                        size="40" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="crevtblRow">
                                <div class="crevtblCell">Contact</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                    <s:textfield name="updateuser.userContact"
                                        value="%{userContact}" size="40" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="crevtblRow">
                                <div class="crevtblCell">Email</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                    <s:textfield name="updateuser.userEmail" value="%{userEmail}"
                                        size="40" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="crevtblRow">
                                <div class="crevtblCell">Date of Birth (YYYY-MM-DD)</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                    <s:textfield name="updateuser.userBirthDate"
                                        value="%{userBirthDate}" size="40" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="crevtblRow">
                                <div class="crevtblCell">Role</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell1">:</div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                    <select name="updateuser.userRole" class="adduserlistbox1">
                                        <option>Admin</option>
                                        <option>User</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="crevtblRow">
                                <div class="crevtblCell"></div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell1"></div>
                                <div class="crevtblCell2">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
                                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                      <a href="viewusers.jsp"  class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </section>
    </s:iterator>
            </s:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Struts2 uses themes to generate HTML](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-themes.html). A different theme, a different HTML in output.

The default theme is `XHTML`, that generate your tags inside `<td>`, among the other things.

Since you've designed your HTML by yourself, and you're using divs instead of tables, **just use the `simple` theme**, that will not append almost any additional HTML to the expected one:

```xml
<s:form action="UpdateUserRoleByAdmin" theme="simple" >
```

If you like the effect, consider applying it once for all the application, by setting in struts.xml the following constant:

```xml
<constant name="struts.ui.theme"    value="simple"/>
```

Comment: Yeah 
Thankyou very much @Andrea sir for solving my problem. :)